# How can I see my removed questions and answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answer, deleted-questions

Just a quick question: How can I see my removed questions and answers?

I have some deleted posts and I would like to read them again.

Also, thanks for saving me from downvotes... I bet I would have lost 200 reputation in 24 hours... That's scary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the [reputation tab on your profile](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/31928/seraph-myrmidon?tab=reputation), make sure "show removed posts" is checked:

[image: screen shot]

Alternatively, if you have at least 10k reputation, search for "deleted:yes" plus any other search terms ("is:q" for questions, keywords, tags...).  This search shows you your own deleted posts but not other users'.

Comment: Note that "deleted:yes" only works for users with [10k+ rep](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @Laurel thanks!  Added.